# Dealing with date issues in AngularJS/HTML5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date

I'm rewriting an old ASP.NET Web Forms application in Angular JS and I'm having some issues with processing dates.

First of all, HTML5 has a new input type of "date" that I'd like to use, however, it must always have a value which I feel is an oversight. This isn't good when you're asking for a user to fill out information and the date in question is optional (e.g. cancellation date for a contract that hasn't been canceled yet). To get around this I had to change the input type to "text" and use a regular expression to ensure the entry is made in the correct format (MM/DD/YYYY).

Second, when displaying a date value in text field, it's always in the UTC format, which isn't desirable. There doesn't appear to be a way to change the format of dates displayed in a textbox when binding to model of type date.

Third, when I call "new Date(dateString)" and dateString doesn't contain a time portion, I would assume the time would default to midnight and it does, but it's also appending the time zone info to it, so when I send this data to my API where it gets written to the database, it has this value: 2016-08-18 07:00:00 (I'm in the Mountain Time Zone which is GMT+7).  I need it to be stored as 2016-08-18 00:00:00.

What I've tried to do is use a $watch function, such as below:

```
    $scope.$watch('contractCancellationDate', function (newValue) {
        if ($scope.contract) {
            if (newValue)
                $scope.contract.cancellationDate = new Date(newValue);
            else
                $scope.contract.cancellationDate = null;
        }
    });

    $scope.$watch('contract.cancellationDate', function (newValue) {
        if (newValue)
            $scope.contractCancellationDate = $filter('date')(newValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
        else
            $scope.contractCancellationDate = null;
    });
```

I have a model class called "contract" with a "cancellationDate" property.  I also created a $scope variable called "contractCancellationDate". Instead of binding my text field to "contract.cancellationDate", I'm binding it to "contractCancellationDate".

What I also find odd is that the regular expression I'm using requires leading zeros for single-digit month/day values and if I attempt to enter a zero as the first character, something is preventing the first keystroke from being accepted but if I hit the 0 key again, it then appears in the textbox. I haven't tried that on a different machine so who knows what's going on there. I do notice however that the watch code executes once all 10 characters of the date are entered and not before (and not specifically tied to the field losing focus). I have set a maxlength of 10 on the field.

Is there a better way to do this? My attempts to deal with this seem pretty kludgey to me and it still isn't working correctly.

Comment: You should look at http://momentjs.com/ for manipulating and formatting dates in javascript.

Comment: have you looked into $formatters and $validators? I think $formatters will help you to change whats been displayed vs whats stored in the model. look into [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: heres a plnkr [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/iPaf3oRQrARL1os3hWxm?p=info) that i created to get you started with $formatters, $parsers and $validators

Comment: moment + a datepicker (ex: http://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/)